# Remove Table Background Hover - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a contact form here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/contact-us/

When you tried to hover on the fields either one by one or the whole table itself it gives the background color dark grey.

[image]

How can I remove that and just have a plain white background and no hover on it?

```
<style type="text/css">
.beta-base .preheader, .beta-base .header, .beta-base .sidebar, .beta-base .body, .beta-base .footer, #mainContent {
    text-align: left;
}
.beta-base .preheader, .beta-base .header, .beta-base .body, .beta-base .sidebar, .beta-base .leftSidebar, .beta-base .rightSidebar, .beta-base .footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}
.beta-base .title, .beta-base .subtitle, .beta-base .text, .beta-base img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.preheader{
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.header {
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.body, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.footer,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.sidebar, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.leftSidebar, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.rightSidebar {
    padding: 20px;
}
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.header p, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.preheader p, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.body p,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.footer p, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.sidebar p,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.leftSidebar p, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.rightSidebar p {
    margin: 0;
    color: inherit;
}
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.header div.title, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.preheader div.title, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.body div.title,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.footer div.title, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.sidebar div.title,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.leftSidebar div.title, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.rightSidebar div.title,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.header div.subtitle, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.preheader div.subtitle, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.body div.subtitle,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.footer div.subtitle, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.sidebar div.subtitle,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.leftSidebar div.subtitle, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.rightSidebar div.subtitle,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.header div.text, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.preheader div.text, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.body div.text, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.body div.text div,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.footer div.text, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.sidebar div.text,
.beta-base .bodyContainer td.leftSidebar div.text, .beta-base .bodyContainer td.rightSidebar div.text {
    overflow: auto;
}
.beta-base .optout {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
div.infusion-captcha {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.infusion-captcha input, div.infusion-captcha select, div.infusion-captcha textarea {
    width: 95%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.infusion-field-container td.infusion-field-input-container input[type='text'],
table.infusion-field-container td.infusion-field-input-container input[type='password'],
table.infusion-field-container td.infusion-field-input-container textarea {
    width: 98%; /* must be 98% to make the snippet-menu line up due to border width */
    margin: 0;
}
table.infusion-field-container td.infusion-field-input-container select {
    width: 101%;
    *width: 102%; /* this one for IE */
    margin: 0;
}
table.infusion-field-container td.infusion-field-label-container {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
td.header .image-snippet img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#webformErrors {
    color: #990000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.infusion-form {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.infusion-option {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.beta-font-b h1, .beta-font-b h2, .beta-font-b h3, .beta-font-b h4, .beta-font-b h5, .beta-font-b h6 {
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b h1 {font-size: 24px;}
.beta-font-b h2 {font-size: 20px;}
.beta-font-b h3 {font-size: 14px;}
.beta-font-b h4 {font-size: 12px;}
.beta-font-b h5 {font-size: 10px;}
.beta-font-b h6 {font-size: 8px;}
.beta-font-b address {font-style: italic;}
.beta-font-b pre {font-family: Courier New, monospace;}
.beta-font-b .title, .beta-font-b .title p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .subtitle, .beta-font-b .subtitle p {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .text, .beta-font-b p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .preheader .text, .beta-font-b .preheader .text p {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .footer a {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .footer .text {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .sidebar .title, .beta-font-b .leftSidebar .title, .beta-font-b .rightSidebar .title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .sidebar .subtitle, .beta-font-b .leftSidebar .subtitle, .beta-font-b .rightSidebar .subtitle {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.beta-font-b .sidebar .text, .beta-font-b .sidebar .text p, .beta-font-b .leftSidebar .text, .beta-font-b .rightSidebar .text {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.infusion-field-label-container {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.infusion-field-input-container {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.infusion-option label {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.default .background{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .title{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .subtitle{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .text{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default a{
color:#0645ad;
;
}
.default .background .preheader .text{
color:#1a242e;
;
}
.default .background .preheader a{
color:#0645ad;
;
}
.default .header{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .header .title{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .header .subtitle{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .header .text{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .header .a{
color:#157DB8;
;
}
.default .hero{
background-color:#025C8D;
;
}
.default .hero .title{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .hero .subtitle{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .hero .text{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .hero .a{
color:#157DB8;
;
}
.default .quote{
background-color:#013B5A;
;
}
.default .quote:after{
border-color:#013B5A transparent transparent transparent;
;
}
.default .quote .title{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .quote .subtitle{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .quote .text{
color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .quote .a{
color:#157DB8;
;
}
.default .body{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .main{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
;
}
.default .main .title{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .main .subtitle{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .main .text{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .main .a{
color:#157DB8;
;
}
.default .sidebar{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .sidebar .title{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .sidebar .subtitle{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .sidebar .text{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .sidebar .a{
color:#157DB8;
;
}
.default .leftSidebar{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .leftSidebar .title{
color:#f15c25;
;
}
.default .leftSidebar .subtitle{
color:#669940;
;
}
.default .rightSidebar{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .rightSidebar .title{
color:#f15c25;
;
}
.default .rightSidebar .subtitle{
color:#669940;
;
}
.default .footer{
background-color:#ffffff;
;
}
.default .footer .text{
color:#0d0d0d;
;
}
.default .footer .title{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .footer a{
color:#1b3bde;
;
}
.default .footer .subtitle{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .infusion-field-label-container{
font-size:14px;
;
}
.default .infusion-field-label-container{
font-family:Arial;
;
}
.default .infusion-field-label-container{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .infusion-field-input{
font-size:14px;
;
}
.default .infusion-option label{
font-size:14px;
;
}
.default .infusion-option label{
font-family:Arial;
;
}
.default .infusion-option label{
color:#000000;
;
}
.default .webFormBodyContainer{
border-width:0px;
;
}
.default .webFormBodyContainer{
border-style:Hidden;
;
}
.default .webFormBodyContainer{
border-color:#000000;
;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.infusion-field-label-container {
text-align:Left;
}
.infusion-field-input-container {
width:200px;
}
.infusion-field-label-container {
vertical-align:Middle;
}
.bodyContainer {
width:425px;
}
</style>
        <div class="default beta-base beta-font-b" id="mainContent" style="height:100%">
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" class="bodyContainer webFormBodyContainer" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="body" sectionid="body" valign="top">
                                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/a74884c5636f18aad3994210d4205f39" class="infusion-form" method="POST">
                                    <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="a74884c5636f18aad3994210d4205f39" />
                                    <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="Contact Us&#a;Form" />
                                    <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.62.0.51" />
                                    <div>
                                    <table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_field_LastName">Last Name *</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
                                    <div>
                                    <table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_field_Email">Email *</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
                                    <div>
                                    <table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_field_Phone1">Phone *</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
                                    <div>
                                    <table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_custom_Country0">Country</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <select id="inf_custom_Country0" name="inf_custom_Country0"><option value="">Please select one</option><option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option><option value="Albania">Albania</option><option value="Algeria">Algeria</option><option value="Andorra">Andorra</option><option value="Angola">Angola</option><option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option><option value="Argentina">Argentina</option><option value="Armenia">Armenia</option><option value="Australia">Australia</option><option value="Austria">Austria</option><option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option><option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option><option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option><option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option><option value="Barbados">Barbados</option><option value="Belarus">Belarus</option><option value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option value="Belize">Belize</option><option value="Benin">Benin</option><option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option><option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option><option value="Botswana">Botswana</option><option value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option value="Brunei">Brunei</option><option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option><option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option><option value="Burundi">Burundi</option><option value="Cabo Verde">Cabo Verde</option><option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option><option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option><option value="Canada">Canada</option><option value="Central African Republic (CAR)">Central African Republic (CAR)</option><option value="Chad">Chad</option><option value="Chile">Chile</option><option value="China">China</option><option value="Colombia">Colombia</option><option value="Comoros">Comoros</option><option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option><option value="Republic of the Congo">Republic of the Congo</option><option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option><option value="Croatia">Croatia</option><option value="Cuba">Cuba</option><option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option><option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option><option value="Denmark">Denmark</option><option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option><option value="Dominica">Dominica</option><option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option><option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><option value="Egypt">Egypt</option><option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option><option value="Estonia">Estonia</option><option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option><option value="Fiji">Fiji</option><option value="Finland">Finland</option><option value="France">France</option><option value="Gabon">Gabon</option><option value="Gambia">Gambia</option><option value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option value="Germany">Germany</option><option value="Ghana">Ghana</option><option value="Greece">Greece</option><option value="Grenada">Grenada</option><option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><option value="Guinea">Guinea</option><option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="Guyana">Guyana</option><option value="Haiti">Haiti</option><option value="Honduras">Honduras</option><option value="Hungary">Hungary</option><option value="Iceland">Iceland</option><option value="India">India</option><option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option><option value="Iran">Iran</option><option value="Iraq">Iraq</option><option value="Ireland">Ireland</option><option value="Israel">Israel</option><option value="Italy">Italy</option><option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option><option value="Japan">Japan</option><option value="Jordan">Jordan</option><option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option><option value="Kenya">Kenya</option><option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option><option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option><option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option><option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="Laos">Laos</option><option value="Latvia">Latvia</option><option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option><option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option><option value="Liberia">Liberia</option><option value="Libya">Libya</option><option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option><option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option><option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option><option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option><option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option><option value="Malawi">Malawi</option><option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option><option value="Maldives">Maldives</option><option value="Mali">Mali</option><option value="Malta">Malta</option><option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option><option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option><option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option><option value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option><option value="Moldova">Moldova</option><option value="Monaco">Monaco</option><option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option><option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option><option value="Morocco">Morocco</option><option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option><option value="Myanmar (Burma)">Myanmar (Burma)</option><option value="Namibia">Namibia</option><option value="Nauru">Nauru</option><option value="Nepal">Nepal</option><option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option><option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option><option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><option value="Niger">Niger</option><option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option><option value="North Korea">North Korea</option><option value="Norway">Norway</option><option value="Oman">Oman</option><option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option><option value="Palau">Palau</option><option value="Palestine">Palestine</option><option value="Panama">Panama</option><option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><option value="Peru">Peru</option><option value="Philippines">Philippines</option><option value="Poland">Poland</option><option value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option value="Qatar">Qatar</option><option value="Romania">Romania</option><option value="Russia">Russia</option><option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option><option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option><option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option><option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option><option value="Samoa">Samoa</option><option value="San Marino">San Marino</option><option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option><option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="Senegal">Senegal</option><option value="Serbia">Serbia</option><option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option><option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option><option value="Singapore">Singapore</option><option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option><option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option><option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option><option value="Somalia">Somalia</option><option value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option value="South Korea">South Korea</option><option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option><option value="Spain">Spain</option><option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option><option value="Sudan">Sudan</option><option value="Suriname">Suriname</option><option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option><option value="Sweden">Sweden</option><option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option value="Syria">Syria</option><option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option><option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option><option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option><option value="Thailand">Thailand</option><option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option><option value="Togo">Togo</option><option value="Tonga">Tonga</option><option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option><option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option><option value="Turkey">Turkey</option><option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option><option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option><option value="Uganda">Uganda</option><option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option><option value="United Arab Emirates (UAE)">United Arab Emirates (UAE)</option><option value="United Kingdom (UK)">United Kingdom (UK)</option><option value="United States of America (USA)">United States of America (USA)</option><option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option><option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option><option value="Vatican City (Holy See)">Vatican City (Holy See)</option><option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option><option value="Zambia">Zambia</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option></select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
                                    <div>
                                    <table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="infusion-field-label-container">
                                    <label for="inf_custom_Message">Message</label>
</td><td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:200px;">
                                    <textarea cols="24" id="inf_custom_Message" name="inf_custom_Message" rows="5">
                                    </textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
                                    <div class="infusion-submit">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

You can use your Google Chromes code inspector to check on this.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could format that code better for us? And please include the relevant CSS in the question itself. Don't send us off site, particularly to a resource that is being developed/changed.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Furthermore, try and avoid the use of tables for layout. You could achieve the same layout with no tables, let alone tables nested 3 deep.

Comment: modified my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The specific CSS that's causing the hover over is as follows:

```
table:not(.shop_table) > tbody > tr:hover > td { background-color: #454545 }
```

And when that removed you have a blue background color as follows:

```
table:not(.shop_table) > tbody > tr:hover > td { background-color: #46a5e5 }
```

So this is where to start. You will need to find them and then decide how to proceed.

You can change the `background-color: #fff`

Or add this:

```
table.background > tbody > tr:hover > td { background-color: #fff }
```

How you proceed is dependent on if changing the **background color** on the existing styles has an adverse effect on other elements. If making this class change does effect other elements on this site (which you don't want to effect), then you will need to add a class selector to the table like:

Currently:

```
<table class="background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
```

Change to:

```
<table class="background monkey" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
```

And add a new style definition to your stylesheet:

```
table.monkey > tbody > tr:hover > td { background-color: #fff }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have background-color: #656565; set to a LOT of selectors in your CSS and since you have extreme amount of nested tables, the background color is applied for every nested row hover by this selector: "table:not(.shop_table)>tbody>tr:hover>td" = desired cell + it's parent cell + it's parent cell are all resolving and changing to the background color. You need to be more specific with your selectors. In your case you already have more specific class names on the individual tables: table.infusion-field-container>tbody>tr:hover>td

Comment: is there a specific CSS we can apply to remove everything with background color - #656565;

Comment: @MatthewMatt Change the css "table:not(.shop_table)>tbody>tr:hover>td" to "table.infusion-field-container>tbody>tr:hover>td" assuming you are not using elsewhere - though I do not know the reasoning behind the '.not' - could also ADD to the 'not' all the classes of the parent tables, which would be "table:not(.shop_table):not(.bodyContainer):not(.background)>tbody>tr:hover>td" instead